# How to get Json from Java SDK for APi.ai

Tags: java, sdk, dialogflow-es

I'm working on an app with API.ai. I want to make my API.ai contexts linked with another API (without using one click integration). To do that, I'm using java sdk for API.ai but I can't find how to get the json from my intent, i mean the entire json made.

Hope to be clear, if anyone could help 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the Test file TestClientApplication.java that's included in the SDK, you can see that it imports `AIRequest` and `AIResponse`. The `AIResponse` class is the JSON object that gets shown when you show JSON on `api.ai`. If you go into the Class itself you can see that it has getters and setters for all the fields in the JSON.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer !